# Shell script to read number of text files from directory and perform arithmetic operations on it

Tags: file, awk

I have got a couple of text files containing student records ( marks of 3 subjects student in a row ) in a directory. Need to read each file from the directory and perform addition operations on the student marks. And verify the total is correct?

File1.txt ( Input file )

```
Class: 1
Student1 25 22 18 65
Student2 15 20 25 60
Student3 19 23 25 67
Total: 192
```

In this way I have got File2, File3 ....etc.

Here I need to add each students marks in 3 subjects and compare it with the total filed ( last field ) and also add each students total marks and compare it with the last field of file Total:

Sample output File1.txt

```
Class: 1
Student1 25 22 18 65
Student2 15 20 10 60
Student3 19 23 25 67
Total: 192

Errors:
Student2 15 20 10 : Total marks is wrong.
Total: 192 : All students total is wrong.
```

So far I have found is:

```
awk '{$2+$3+$4=$temp_var}' File1.txt
```

Reading student marks from a File1 and adding them.

Comment: Yes, after the 3 students marks record there is a filed called Total: 192                We need add all the marks of 3 students ( 65+60+67 ) And verify it with the Total field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution applied to files in loop:

```
for f in File*.txt; do 
    awk 'NR>1{ a[$1]=$2+$3+$4 }{ print }END{ printf("\n"); 
         for(i in a) print i,"total marks",a[i] }' "$f" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$f"; 
done
```

---

Exemplary result:

```
> cat File1.txt 
Class: 1
Student1 25 22 18
Student2 15 20 25
Student3 19 23 25

Student1 total marks 65
Student2 total marks 60
Student3 total marks 67
```

---

Details:

- `NR>1` - skip the 1st (*header*) line
- `a[$1]=$2+$3+$4` - accumulating total *mark* sum for each *student*

Comment: Thank you RomanPerekhrest for your reply. Can you please go through the updated question and help me to provide a solution for the same.

Comment: @user8167164, that differs much from your initial condition. I would recommend you to create a new question. Also, you have posted only error output, but there should be also "success" ouptut